# R.Java Keeps on reverting after it has been modified to solve the error

Tags: java, android

I have here a simple android application and I can't save the solution for my error because its in the R.java file. It just keep on reverting and I can't save what I modified.

here is the code that I'm working on. Its just a simple text to speech buttons.

```
private TextToSpeech talker;
private ImageButton imageButton1;
private TextView text;`

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abc);

    talker = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("A");
imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String strText2 = text.getText().toString();
        if (strText2.length()>0)
        { say(strText2); }

    }
});`
```

I have my error on `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);` because it can't find the resource id which is supposed to be saved in R.java file. My problem is whenever I click the suggested solution, which is creating field text in type id, and the error will be gone and if I save it, it just revert back.

Comment: You cannot modify R.java.  It is recreated automatically every build.  Instead, you should work out why the `TextView` with id `text` cannot be found in your layout.  Start by editing your question and adding the layout XML.  Ignore the automatic fix, it won't work.

Comment: I once had an issue with old versions of R.java. Try simply deleting it and compile everything again. EDIT: that was with netbeans.

Comment: clean your project to fix the changes you have made to the layout. R.java will automatically be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it tells you to create the id of the view you want to find using findViewByID, the id doesnt exist. If you just create that id in the R.java you would have solved the symptom but not the problem.

You are inflating `R.layout.abc` so i guess that the View you want to find is within that xml.

you need to add `android:id="@+id/imageButton1"` to the Button you are trying to retrieve in your code. If that still throws some sort of error, clean the project.

Edit:

if you want to add a TextView to the layout, you need to add an id to the layout that is supposed to host the TextView, retrieve the Layout like

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
ll.addView(tv);
tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

now you have a new textview within your view.

Comment: Yeah you got it right but can I set the text view not visible?

Comment: i couldnt imagine why you would like to add an invisible textView, but yes you can. updated code

Comment: because I want the text to speech say it without the text view ruining the pictures in my xml. :) but Thank you for your answer. :))

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to fix problems by editing `R.java`.  Instead, look for the root cause of the problem in the XML layout file that `R.java` is generated from ... and fix the XML.

Note that the start of the `R.java` file has this comment:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY. 
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
```

I don't see how they could state this more clearly.

Comment: If I put the xml here it'll be long and in the xml I don't have the textview there. I want to declare the textview without having another object in my xml except for all the buttons. Well I'm new but is that even possible? I have tried it before only pure java leaving the xml clean.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: he wants to add a TextView to the View without declaring it in the xml. So he wants to programmatically add a new TextView.

Comment: I use pure java in showing all the objects that can be shown in the xml layout.

Comment: @Rii - whatever you are trying to do, you CANNOT do it by modifying the R.java file.  Put your code in some other class.